# Add text inside html/xml tag with php

Tags: php, html, xml, html-parsing

I am trying to add text inside a html tag:

```
$html = '<html>
<head>
   <title>title</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:yellow;">
   <p>some text</p>
</body>
</html>';
```

now I want this to appear at the end of the body tag:

```
$replacement = '<footer>Footer Text</footer>';
```

so that the result would look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>title</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:yellow;">
   <p>some text</p>
   <footer>Footer Text</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked for a similar answer with preg- or ereg replace but there only where solutions where the text is replaced completely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$new_html= str_replace("</body>", "<footer>Footer Text</footer></body>", $html);
```